# What OOP concepts applied in MVC?

Tags: ios, design-patterns

Yesterday I had an interview over iOS and the interviewer asked, what OOP concepts are applicable in MVC design pattern for which I had no clue can anybody put some light one this.

Comment: Isn't MVC independant of OOP? I'm pretty sure all OOP concept can fit in MVC if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Developer.Apple.com, Fundamental iOS Design Patterns are:-

"No matter what type of app you are creating, there are a few fundamental design patterns and techniques that you must know before you start writing code. In iOS, the system frameworks provide critical infrastructure for your app and in most cases are the only way to access the underlying hardware. In turn, the frameworks use many specific design patterns and assume that you are familiar with them. Understanding these design patterns is therefore an important first step to understanding how the system can help you develop your app.

The most important design patterns you must know are:

```
Model-View-Controller—This design pattern governs the overall structure of your app.

Delegation—This design pattern facilitates the transfer information and data from one object to another.

Target-action—This design pattern translates user interactions with buttons and controls into code that your app can execute.

Block objects—You use blocks to implement callbacks and asynchronous code.

Sandboxing—All iOS apps are placed in sandboxes to protect the system and other apps. The structure of the sandbox affects the placement of your app’s files and has implications for data backups and some app-related features.
```

Accurate and efficient memory management is important for iOS apps. Because iOS apps typically have less usable memory than a comparable desktop computer, apps need to be aggressive about deleting unneeded objects and be lazy about creating objects in the first place. Apps use the compiler’s Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) feature to manage memory efficiently. Although using ARC is not required, it is highly recommended. The alternative is to manage memory yourself by explicitly retaining and releasing objects."

Also Read this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DesignPatterns.html

EDIT :

For programming Examples:

http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f12/presentation-materials/myrose.pdf

Comment: I think that you misinterpreted the question the discussion here is what OOP concepts actually applied in these design patterns MVC to be more particular

Answer (score 0):

**Not an exhaustive list..**

Inheritance: UIView is often subclassed.

Polymophism. See inheritance.

Design Pattern Model-Viewer-Controller: That's what MVC stands for.

Design pattern Observer: Used extensively in MVC.

**Design patterns specificly used in iOS implementation of MVC:**

Composite and Chain of Command: Windows and Views pass on messages to subviews.

Adaptor: Often used for delayed load of an UIView etc.

Flyweight: Used in UITable

Comment: can you explain by taking some real life example I had a long surfing session over the web but couldnt'f find any concrete example

Comment: Just about any iOS programming cookbook is full of examples that highlight these things. But they just rarely make the OOP connection, as they are for practical guys. Skim the listed Design Patterns on Wikipedia, then take a look at some iOS code. They will jump right out! Flyweight (UITable), Composite/Chain of Responsibility (touch event handling) and inheritance (subclassing UIView etc) is everywhere.